# Convert 3D mesh to 2D and place it on WPF Canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas

Is it possible to convert 3D object from Viewport3D and show it on Canvas, but conversion MUST NOT be depended from a camera position and its view point.
By another words using WPF i would like to make 4 views like in 3Ds Max, such as: Perspective (for 3D objects) and Front, Top, Left views (for 2D ). 
Perspective view is a Viewport3D, but how show all 3D objects from the Viewport to the other views - Top, Front and Left ?

Comment: The 2D views are actually still 3d renderings, but from a particular vantage point and typically using an orthographic rather than perspective projection.  You change the type of projection by modifying the View matrix (not sure if the Viewport3D supports this, but I would suspect it does.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematically speaking, no, it's not possible.

However, you should be able to simulate that by specifying a Camera Position that *is* top, front, and left. Can't you calculate approximately where that is based on the bounds of the 3D object?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates#Use_in_computer_graphics